# How to get only latest logged event via Web3 API?

Tags: web3js

Is there a way to get only latest log for e.g `myContractInstance.myEvent`? Don't wanna rewind whole past. I know I can pass `latest` to a filter object, but that's not quite what I want. I'd like to get latest one from the past (no matter at which block it happened) and then continue listening for a new ones. Is this possible?

Comment: Would you know a rough upper bound on how long ago the last event would have been produced? Also, have you considered using a state variable in your contract instead of an event? Seems like that's more suited to your use case

Comment: yea, indeed, it can be solved with state variable. I was just curious if such thing is possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about `{fromBlock: "latest", toBlock: "latest" }`?

Comment: hmm, I don't think this is it. For example if `myEvent` was executed 20 times during lifetime of a smart-contract. I want to get that 20th time, I don't care if it was called 20th time in latest, first, or whichever block

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a state variable indeed. If only to store `block.number`.